# Transfer project from Xamarin.Android to Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the project on Xamarin.Android.
In **MainActivity.cs**:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    LinearLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.MyLinearLayout);
    Android.Widget.RelativeLayout rl = new Android.Widget.RelativeLayout(this);
    ...
    mainLayout.AddView (rl);
 }
```

Can I add on MainPage *only Android.Widget.RelativeLayout* in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mix native Android/iOS/Windows and Xamarin.Forms. Here are examples of that:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

If you want to have native Android view only on you MainPage, you could make a custom renderer for MainPage (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) and add your Android Views inside renderer.